# Set Wordpress comment_content length

Tags: wordpress

Hi all is there a way I can limit the length of comment_content in Wordpress. I am creating a view of the last 5 comments of a page but want to limit the length.

This is the code I have so far:

```
<?php $args = array ( 'post_id' => '225', 'number' => '5', 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC', 'comment_approved' => '1' );

     $comments = get_comments($args);
       foreach($comments as $comment) :
        echo('<div class="sidebarNewsTitle">'. $comment->comment_author . ' said : "' . strip_tags($comment->comment_content). '..."</div>');
       endforeach;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
add_action( 'preprocess_comment', 'ct_minimum_comment_length', 8 );

function ct_minimum_comment_length( $commentdata ){
    $minlength = 20;//minimal length you want to limit the comment content
    preg_match_all( '/./u', trim( $commentdata['comment_content'] ), $maxlength );
    $maxlength = count( $maxlength[0] );
    if( $maxlength < $minlength ) {
        wp_die( sprintf(_('Come on buddy, say at least %s characters', 'ct'), $minlength ));
    }
    return $commentdata;
}
```

Reference: 
http://clonetemplates.com/codex/limit-minimal-length-comment-content-wordpress.html/
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/preprocess_comment

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could try to limit length of comments with `wp_trim_words()` function which allows you to set the character/words limit for a specific block of content.

To learn more about this function check [this article](http://thomasgriffinmedia.com/blog/2012/09/limit-content-length-in-wordpress-with-wp_trim_words/).

But it is better to make your users aware of the limit, so using [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gregs-comment-length-limiter/) would probably be a better choice.

With this plugin you set:

> limit on the length of comments left in the comment form, with a
>   character countdown displayed for the user and dynamically updated
>   with each keypress.

Answer (score 0):

There is a cool, new plugin with that you can set the minimum and maximum texts for comments. You can also edit the texts. Its called "Control Comment Length"

Check it out at http://greenitsolutions.at/control-comment-length-wordpress-plugin-by-greenitsolutions-at/ or on wordpress.org